# File saving to server as invalid JSON

Tags: php, ajax, json, encoding, server-side

I am saving json to the server using a PHP script as follows:

```
<?php

$json = $_POST['json'];
$file = fopen('jsonfile.json', 'wb');
fwrite($file, $json);
fclose($file);


?>
```

The script reads in the existing jsonfile.json file and writes the new json to it...then saves it to the server.  But this results in invalid json.  I know that the actual json is indeed valid because if I use document.write() to show the json in the browser, and copy/paste that json to a validator it is perfect. But the actual json in the file that has been written to the server is invalid and therefore unuseable to any program.

I am assumiming it has something to so with encoding. I have tried using headers that enforce UTF-8 in the php script but to no avail.

The json looks like this:

```
{  
   "name":"First Name",
   "children":[  
      {  
         "name":"Second Name",
         "children":[  
            {  
               "name":"Third Name",
               "children":[  
                  {
```

and so on....

Again, this IS valid JSON as when using document.write() and pasting into a validator it is fine. If I were to show the json in the file that has been written to the server it would look identical. It's like there is some hidden formatting we don't see not allowing a validator to pass it and obviously not allowing programs to run it.

Here is the AJAX to POST the json to the php script:

```
$.ajax({
         url: 'json.php',
         data: {
         json: theJsonBeingWritten
         },
         dataType: "json",
         type: "POST"
         });
```

This sucessfully writes the file to the server, but something is wrong with the format/characters(?)

I have also tried adding processData: false to the AJAX section in order to stop conversion into whatever PHP is turning my json into. I also tried using JSON.stringify({json: theJsonBeingWritten}) to the data: section of ajax but to no avail. I have also tried using $.post( "json.php", theJsonBeingWritten ); instead of $.ajax but this also did not work. I have also set the content-type to Content-type: application/json".

Comment: **Where** did you get an error indicating that your JSON file was invalid? Show the code that tries to read it. Have you checked your .json file with a hexeditor? An invalid string encoding would just result in `null` values.

Comment: how are you getting "theJsonBeingWritten"?

Comment: Open the .json file in notepad (or my preference notepad++) and see if the contents is valid json.

Comment: I am getting the error from an online validator when copying/pasting from the file that was written to the server. But it isn't anything that can be seen with the naked eye. It's like an underling encoding or something. The theJsonBeingWritten is from a string that has been formatted in structure to look like json...then stringified and parsed to actually be json. But again...it DOES produce valid json...it is the file that is the problem.

Comment: What does the validator say?  Like the comment above, you might try copy/pasting into a text editor that can re-encode stuff for you to see if that will pass validation.

Comment: Yes that does pass validation...but it isn't useful if this has to be done manually. I need to have the server-side script write valid json to the file. The validator says double quotes must be used...so it's like it isnt "seeing" the doulbe quotes as double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was finally able to discover the sneaky little symbols in the JSON. These did not appear in any text editor or hex-editor or validator. Only until seeing the JSON from the raw URL did the circumflex symbols appear. Something in the PHP fwrite() function was forcing these in despite any attempts at forcing encoding. Anyway, using the following to remove the characters from the json in the PHP script prior to using fwrite() did the trick:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with fopen..

```
$a = fopen("data.json", "w");
fwrite($a,$json);
fclose($a);
```

this will write whatever string $json to the file data.json